# Loading data using as3 URLLoader from ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionscript-3

ASP.NET controller:

```
// GET api/assets/5
public string Get(int id)
{
    ... <some DB init here>
    string sResult = (string)oCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return sResult;
}
```

AS3 Receiver:

```
private function btnLoad_Click():void
{
    try
    {
        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://192.168.55.100/getimage/api/assets/1");
        oUrlLoader = new URLLoader();
        oUrlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        oUrlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLDataLoaded, false, 0, true);
        oUrlLoader.load(urlRequest);
    }
    catch (ex:Error) {}
}
protected function onXMLDataLoaded(evt:Event):void {    
    try
    {
        var sData:String = oUrlLoader.data.toString();
        editor.paste_fromserver( XML(sData));
    }
    catch (ex:Error) { trace(ex.message); }
}
```

Now what i try to do is to parse string as XML, but all i get is error: "Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed."

What i've found is when i watch oUrlLoader.data in "Watch Expression" the value is there, but sData = oUrlLoader.data = """" (empty string?).

Also tried oUrlLoader.data.toString() - didn't help, but watch expression changed a bit, without toString() it had two "" signs in the beggining of value, with toString() it had only one ".

**Any ideas why oUrlLoader.data in Watch Expression value is set, but the same oUrlLoader.data in code does not return any string?**

P.S. This is actually string value (SVG image), not binary data. I'm using Flash Builder for as3.

**EDIT:**

Hehe, sData also have a value in Watch Expression. The data is:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\"><svg version=\"1.2\" id=\"svg2\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:svg=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\"><circle cx=\"284\" cy=\"310\" r=\"150\" id=\"untitled\" transform=\"matrix(1,0,0,1,-37,-22)\" style=\"opacity:1;stroke:#44F247;fill:#F087CA;fill-opacity:1;stroke-opacity:0.54;stroke-width:35.1;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-linecap:none;stroke-linejoin:round;\"/></svg>"
```

When i copy this data and paste it directly in code it works, but using this urlLoader it does not work... :(

**EDIT2:**

Screenshot from builder (watch expressions have value, sData in code, when mouse over - does not):
http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/7471/o7sa.png

and also... :] this string does not contain any tabs, new lines or other white spaces in source database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the retrieved data/text from the server. It is full of backslashes. While it works well as an escape character when writing text directly in the code, it is not supposed to be in retrieved data.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! :D I've changed MVC api controller to standart controller and this did help, now string does not contain escape chars.